# jQuery-ui: How do I access options from inside private functions

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-plugins, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am learning to write jquery-ui plugins using the widget-factory pattern. For cleaner organization, I have some helper methods defined inside the object literal that is passed to  `$.widget`. I would like to access the options object in those helpers. For example in the boilerplate below, how do I access the options object inside `_helper()`?

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    $.widget( "namespace.widgetName" , {

        options: {
            someValue: null
        },

        _create: function () {
            // initialize something....
        },

        destroy: function () {

            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        },

        _helper: function () {
            // I want to access options here.
            // "this" points to the dom element, 
            // not this object literal, therefore this.options wont work
            console.log('methodB called');
        },

        _setOption: function ( key, value ) {
            switch (key) {
            case "someValue":
                //this.options.someValue = doSomethingWith( value );
                break;
            default:
                //this.options[ key ] = value;
                break;
            }
            $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply( this, arguments );
        }
    });

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Aren't methods with a leading underscore considered private by the widget factory? So how are you calling `_helper`?

Comment: Well, in the _create method, this points to the object literal (2nd arg to $.widget) and therefore can be called inside _create as this._helper()

Comment: But you say that '"this" points to the dom element' so what does the `._helper()` call look like? And `_create` is a special method that's part of the widget interface.

Comment: _helper is in fact a handler for a 'click' event which is set in _create like so: $(some_selector).click(this._helper). The event subsystem therefore calls it on a DOM element. I was looking for a way to use the options property inside _helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're doing this inside your `_create`:

```
$(some_selector).click(this._helper)
```

and you want `this` inside the `_helper` to be the `this` on `this._helper` (i.e. your widget).

There are various solutions:

1. You could use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

   ```
   $(some_selector).click($.bind(this._helper, this));
   ```

   Underscore also has [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) and there's a native [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you don't have to worry about JavaScript version issues). Other libraries will have their own function binding tools. You already have jQuery in play so `$.proxy` is already available and portable as well.
2. You could use the standard `var _this = this;` trick proxy the `_helper` call yourself:

   ```
   var _this = this;
   $(some_selector).click(function() { _this._helper() });
   ```
3. You could use the [`eventData` form of `click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

   ```
   $(some_selector).click({ self: this }, this._helper);
   ```

   and then in `_helper`:

   ```
   _helper: function(ev) {
       var self = ev.data.self;
       // 'self' is the 'this' you're looking for.
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: In the meanwhile I tried passing options as a part of the event.data to bind and that works as expected.  But Thanks for the proxy solution - it helped me add one more trick to my growing jquery skills :). Have accepted your answer

Comment: @Ya.Perelman: Right, the `eventData` is another option, I'll add that for completeness. I do a lot of Backbone stuff lately so my brain always reaches for the binding solutions.